# ¿Cómo manejar los roles y privilegios con spring security?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-security

Soy nuevo con esto de spring, estoy utilizando spring security. Deseo implementar varios roles y una vista para crear más roles y asignarle a cada rol distintas vistas y también distintos permisos sobre cada vista (CRUD).

Inicialmente tengo en el método *configure(HttpSecurity http) de la clase con la anotación @Configuration* lo siguiente para los roles actuales que hay en la base de datos.

```
    for (RolePrivilegeConfig rolePrivilegeConfig : rolePrivilegesConfig) {

            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,rolePrivilegeConfig.getResource())
            .hasRole(rolePrivilegeConfig.getRoleName())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,rolePrivilegeConfig.getResource())
            .hasRole(rolePrivilegeConfig.getRoleName());                         
        } http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login","login","/resources/**").permitAll()
          .anyRequest()           
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
          .loginPage("/login")
          .permitAll()
          .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
          .and()
          .logout().
          logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).
          and()
          .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        //Pagina de retorno al hacer logout
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
          .and()    
          .rememberMe()
          .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository(dataSource))
         .userDetailsService(userDecoratorDetailsService);
```

Hasta el momento funciona correctamente para los roles existentes, pero en caso de agregar un nuevo rol debo reiniciar la app para que se vuelva a aplicar la configuración, **¿existe alguna forma de ejecutar de nuevo la configuración sin reiniciar el servidor?**

Por otro lado quiero implementar permisos en cuanto a CRUDs en cada vista, lo único que se me ocurre en crear otra tabla donde guarde: la vista, el rol y cada acción disponible, cargar en sesión todas estos permisos dependiendo del rol del usuario logueado y del lado de js de alguna forma ocultar las acciones que no tenga permitido el usuario, cada vez que ingrese a una vista, igualmente validar del lado del back cada acción y rol.

El UserDetailsService es el siguiente:

```
@Service
public class UserDecoratorDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserRepository.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userRepository")
private IUserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

/*
 * Busca usuario por userName, utilizado para login con security y para rememberme
 * */
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user=userRepository.findByUserName(username);

    if(user==null) {
        logger.error("Intento de login con: "+username);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario "+username+" no registrado");
    }
    return new UserDetailsDecorator(user);

}

}
```

El Usuario tiene una lista de roles que le cargo al momento de invocar el loadUserByUserName.

```
@Component
public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9088923556385533335L;

public final static String STATUS_ACTIVE="A";
public final static String STATUS_INACTIVE="I";
public final static String STATUS_PASS_EXPIRED="E";

private Long userId;
private String userName;
private String pass;
private Collection<Role> roles;
private Collection<Ips> iippss;
//Estado del usuario A:Active, I:Inactive, D: Deleted
private String status;
```

UserDetailsDecorator

```
public class UserDetailsDecorator implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


private User user;

public UserDetailsDecorator(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}


 @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        this.user.getRoles().forEach(r -> {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority>  authorityList= getGrantedAuthorities(r.getPrivileges());



            authorities.addAll(authorityList);

        });

        return authorities;
    }


 private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Collection<Privilege> privileges) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Privilege privilege : privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege.getResource()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }


@Override
public String getPassword() {       
    return this.user.getPass();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {       
    return this.user.getUserName();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {      
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return  this.user.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(User.STATUS_ACTIVE);
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

}
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier sugerencia o documentación que pueda servirme de ayuda.

Comment: Mira las anotaciones de Spring, por ejemplo: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security . Es un tema muy amplio

Comment: Gracias, me podría servir de mucho y en vez de tener vista para crear roles, puedo definir role_editor, role_eliminar, role_listar, auque igual debo validar de alguna forma del lado del front para mostrat/ocultar las acciones... gracias

Comment: Agregando al comentario de Pablo Lozano, podrias tambien agregar las Tags de Spring Security en tus JSP para renderizar o no ciertas partes de tu vista dependiendo de los roles, checa este ejemplo: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-taglibs . Sobre los roles deberian de actualizarse a cada usuario si este cierra y vuelve a iniciar sesion, checa tu metodos en rolePrivilegeConfig verifica si esta actualizando la consulta para obtener los roles cada vez que el usuario inicia sesion

Comment: @EduardoMarin Muchas gracias, no tenia idea de los taglibs, de seguro me va a ser de gran ayuda, en cuanto a los roles: estos los cargo mediante un service  en la clase  "@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity" 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, en el método configure(HttpSecurity http), no sabría como hacer que se cargue de nuevo esta configuración cada vez que se crea un nuevo rol o se agregan privilegios a un rol existente. O no se si sería mejor idea configurar todos los roles que vaya a utilizar de una vez en la bd o incluso quemados en la config, gracias.

Comment: @JhonArias Me refiero a tu metodo loadByUserName que implementa la clase UserDetailsService de Spring, ahi cargas los permisos al objeto que implementa UserDetails, tus roles los jalas de tu bd o los tienes alojados en tu clase? podrias subir tu codigo para la asignacion de roles?

Comment: @EduardoMarin Agregué al final el UserDetails service, me dices que es mejor ahí asignar los roles al usuario que obtengo desde la bd? para la asignación solo guardo el id del usuario y el rol en la bd por ahora, no tengo más lógica de asignación de roles. Ya todos los roles del sistema los cargo en el "@Configuration"

Comment: Si, puedes asignar tus roles cada ves que crees la implementacion de tu objeto UserDetails agregando un Set<GrantedAuthority>. Puedes hacer esto agregando el este campo a tu objeto User y hacer una Query OneToMany o un EntityGraph , no se si me de a entender. Encontre este tutorial pero siento que es algo ambiguo igual si te puede ayuda: https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration

Comment: @EduardoMarin Muchas gracias, he hecho varios cambios pero aún no lo consigo, ahora se está logueando correctamente pero cuando agrego los matches de todos los roles y privilegios   
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,rolePrivilegeConfig.getResource())
    .hasAuthority(rolePrivilegeConfig.getRoleName()); me bloquea el acceso a dichos privilegios, aúnque el rol tenga dicho privilegio. Agrego el UserDetailsDecorator